# Is a global or static declaration safer in an embedded environment?

Tags: c, embedded

I have a choice to between declaring a variable static or global.

I want to use the variable in one function to maintain counter.

for example

```
void count()
{
   static int a=0;
   for(i=0;i<7;i++)
   {
      a++;
   }

}
```

My other choice is to declare the variable a as global.
I will only use it in this function count().

Which way is the safest solution?

Comment: define safe here, global variables are never "safe".

Comment: I disagree with Anders' suggestion that global variables are never safe, they can be used effectively and appropriately in some cases, but we still need a better definition of "safe".

Comment: @Anders: I'd agree that global variables are rarely - if ever - a good idea, but saying they are "*never* safe" is something I wouldn't agree with.

Comment: @Kevin, read [A pox on globals](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/break-point/4025723/A-pox-on-globals) and tell us if you change your mind.  A global may be entirely safe if the code is never maintained or reused, it is in maintenance that it becomes unsafe, it is an unnecessary and uncontrolled interface to the code, that may be abused.  I would say perhaps that globals are *never necessary* and always *ill-advised*.  C provides three levels of scope; block-local, compilation unit, and global.  Always use the most restrictive possible.

Comment: For the past ten years I have worked with realtime embedded systems in C and I have never used a global. So not only are they dangerous, they are superfluous too. static + set/get functions work fine in 99% of the cases, and in the very few cases where you need extreme realtime performance, you can use inlining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It matters only at compile and link-time. A `static` local variable should be stored and initialised in exactly the same way as a global one.

Declaring a local `static` variable only affects its visibility at the language level, making it visible only in the enclosing function, though with a global lifetime.

A global variable (or any object in general) not marked `static` has external linkage and the linker will consider the symbol when merging each of the object files.

A global variable marked `static` only has internal linkage within the current translation unit, and the linker will not see such a symbol when merging the individual translation units.

Comment: but i only want to use that variable in this function so may be static is good rather than global

Comment: @Sam_k: indeed it's a better stylistic decision, I'm just saying that this difference wouldn't affect the program at runtime.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: On many architectures there is no difference between static and global, from a machine code perspective.  However, this is not true on all modern "big" systems like desktops, when shared libraries are involved.  In some cases, globals get an extra layer of indirection that static variables do not.  This certainly does not apply to smaller embedded systems, however, so this entire comment is really just tangential.

Comment: This answer describes the nature of static variables, but studiously avoids answering the question. You speak of the compile/link-time differences as if they were not important.  Let's say this code formed part of a library rather than a finished executable, or that the code were to be reused in many projects (as good code should be).  Some user of this code who sees a global variable may reasonably assume that it is a legitimate interface and access it.  This answer is dangerous.  The correct answer is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The internal static is probably better from a code-readability point of view, if you'll only ever use it inside that function.

If it was global, some other function could potentially modify it, which could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Either using global or static variable within a function both are not safe because then your function will no longer be **re-entrant**.

However if you are not concerned with function being re-entrant then you can have either based on your choice.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think is **there is anything special with static & normal global with embedded domain** ...!!

in one way static is good that if you are going to initialize your counter as o in starting then if you just declare with static then there is no need to initialize with it 0 because every static varaible is by default initialized with 0.

**Edit :** 
After Clifford's comment i have checked and get to know that globals are also statically allocated and  initialised to zero, so that advantage does not exist..

Comment: this is one difference ::: Declaring a local static variable only affects its visibility at the language level, making it visible only in the enclosing function, though with a global lifetime.

Comment: ya you are right but this behaviour does not have any special meaning in embedded domain..! no cons or pons in embeded with this > it has the same effect at everywhere

Comment: I don't think its just about initializations. _static_ limits the scope to the function in which it was declared, whereas _global_ has scope throughout the program. It _does_ make a difference.

Comment: ya it makes difference at everywhere where you write code notheing special about that in embedded

Comment: thats correct, it should not make difference. All I meant was I think _**this**_ particular example should use static since he wants to use it only in one function

Comment: But globals are *also* statically allocated and therefore also guaranteed by the language standard to be initialised to zero, so the "advantage" you speak of does not exist.  Don't confuse static linkage with static allocation, (even if the language uses the same keyword for both!). It is the static allocation that causes zero initialisation.  That said some embedded compilers for small targets, have an option to deliberately not perform zero initialisation for start-up performance reasons, so it would be a brave programmer to rely on that behaviour.

Comment: Oops I just wrote a whole answer regarding this zero initialization issue before I found Clifford's comment. Indeed, this non-standard skipping of static zero initialization is what makes embedded systems different in this matter.

Comment: @Clifford and Lundin thanks for improving my mis-understanding. i have updated my answer.!!

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is only to be accessed within the function count() then it is by definition *local*, so I cannot see why the question arises. As a rule, always use the most restrictive scope possible for *any* symbol.

You should really read Jack Ganssle's article [A Pox on Globals](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/break-point/4025723/A-pox-on-globals), it will be enlightening.

Comment: totally agree with "it is by definition local, so I cannot see why the question arises" all this thread is one big misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Always reduce scope as far as possible. If a variable doesn't need to be visible outside a function, it should not be declared outside it either. The static keyword should be used whenever possible. If you declare a variable at file scope, it should always be static to reduce the scope to the file it was declared in. This is C's way of private encapsulation.

The above is true for all systems. For embedded there is another concern: all variables declared as static ***or*** global must be initialized before the program is started. This is enforced by ISO C. So they are always set either to the value the programmer wants them initialized to. If the programmer didn't set any value they are initialized to zero (or NULL).

This means that before main is called, there must be a snippet executed in your program that sets all these static/global values. In an embedded system, the initialization values are copied from ROM (flash, eeprom etc) to RAM. A standard C compiler handles this by creating this snippet and adding it to your program.

However, in embedded systems this snippet is often unfortunate, as it leads to a delay at program startup, especially if there is lots of statics/globals. A common non-standard optimization most embedded compilers support, is to remove this snippet. The program will then no longer behave as expected by the C standard, but it will be faster. Once you have done this optimization, initialization must be done in runtime, roughly `static int x; x=0;` rather than `static int x=0;`.

To make your program portable to such non-standard embedded compilers, it is a good habit to always set your globals/statics in runtime. And no matter if you intend to port to such compilers or not, it is certainly a good habit not to rely on the default zero initialization of globals/statics. Because most rookie C programmers don't even know that this static zero initialization rule exists and they will get very confused if you don't init your variables explicitly before using them.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a pointer to a "standard" variable instead

```
void count(int *a) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        (*a)++;
    }
}
```

This way you do not rely neither on global variables nor on static local variables, which makes your program better.

Answer (score -2):

I would say *static* is better than global if you want only one function to access it in which you declared it . Plus global variables are more prone to be accidentally accessed by other functions.

If you *do* want to use globals since it can be accessed by other functions in the program, make sure you declare them as *volatile* .

```
volatile int a = 0;
```

*volatile* makes sure it is not optimised by compilers in the wrong way.

Comment: "volatile" makes sense if the variable could be used in several threads at the same time. The compiler just doesn't make optimizations based on the assumption that the variable cannot be modified by itself.

Comment: @xappymah: Of course, compiler writers are not stupid :) . I just meant that if the variable in question was being updated from an Interrupt Service Routine , which is often the case in embedded programming, then _volatile_ is a must.

Comment: i'm not good in embedded programming so if it is the case then i take back my comment.

Comment: But he explicitly said the variable was only accessed in count(), so the question of access from another thread or ISR does not arise.

Comment: The dangerous compiler optimization bug because of missing volatile is the same for globals shared by several threads, as for globals shared with an ISR. But they should only be declared `static volatile int` if they are indeed shared, otherwise the volatile keyword only does harm.